# C++ If I write a function template and don’t request any instantiations of it, will any template functions be generated from it?

Tags: c++, templates

just asking a question ive been pondering about in the last chapter of my textbook i read

"If I write a function template and don’t request any instantiations of it, will any template functions
be generated from it?"

I believe its false because if you dont ask explicitly through an instantiation then the template cannot be created. Thoughts?

Comment: No. Templates are not code. They are instructions to the compiler on *how* to write functions or classes when it finds invocations or definitions in your code with C++ types in the places where template parameters are in the corresponding template definition(s).

Comment: there are no "template functions", I suppose you mean "..will any functions be generated from it?". If you don't tell the compiler what the template parameters should be, how would it pick them?

Comment: Your intuition is correct. "if you dont ask explicitly through an instantiation then the template cannot be created. "

Comment: It's like doing `#define FOO 7` and never using `FOO` anywhere.  Except templates are part of the core language rather than the preprocessor, so occur at different points in the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

A class template by itself is not a type, or an object, or any other entity.

No code is generated from a source file that contains only template definitions. 
In order for any code to appear, a template must be instantiated: the template arguments must be provided so that the compiler can generate an actual class (or function, from a function template).

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates